# Role Scoper, don't allow other users to see pending posts

Tags: user-roles

I have noticed in Role Scoper recently (sure it wasn't always like this) that contributors can see all the pending posts of all users. Basically I have it set up so users have to submit their posts for review. But I don't really want any posts to be public in any way other then to admins and the user them self until it's been approved.

Can't figure out how I'd set that in role scoper, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solutin, using the following plugin: http://code.mincus.com/41/manage-your-posts-only-in-wordpress/